# How to add custom text if text overflows like '...more'

Tags: html, css

```
#limitedText{
      padding:3px 0px 0px 29px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: left;
      letter-spacing: 0px;
      color: #7B7B7B;
      opacity: 1;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 2; 
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    }
```

I am using the above css, but this is appending only '...'. But I want '...more'.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change `text-overflow` in that manner. What you could do is add a pseudo element, that displays the text you want and give it a white background. It's not a perfect solution to what you were looking for, but it's pretty close:

```css
#limitedText {
  padding: 3px 0px 0px 29px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #7B7B7B;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

#limitedText:after {
  display: block;
  content: "...more";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255)40%);
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p id="limitedText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Comment: according to the mdn documentation on text-overflow only firefox supports a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#Browser_compatibility